Relationship discrete algebraic Riccati and discrete Lyapunov equation
Suppose that $K$ is the optimal control for an LQR problem with inputs $(A,B,Q,R)$, i.e.:
$$ K = -(B^\top P B + R)^{-1} B^\top P A$$
where $P$ solves the discrete algebraic Riccati equation:
$$P = A^\top P A + Q - A^\top P B(B^\top P B + R)^{-1} B^\top P A.$$
Then suppose that $P_K$ solves:
$$P_K = Q + K^\top R K + (A - BK)^\top P_K (A - BK).$$
In other words, $P_K$ solves the discrete Lyapunov equation with parameters $(A-BK)^\top$ and $Q+K^\top R K$.
Is it true that $P_K = P$, and if so, how can we show that?

I think the answer is yes, modulo changing the sign convention $+K$ instead of $-K$ in the second equation. Via algebraic manipulation you can show that the first equation is equivalent to the second. Hint: Use $K^\top RK=K^\top (R+B^\top PB)K-K^\top B^\top P BK$ and the expression for $K$..
